# Tabs en html se resetean al recargar página aspx

Tags: javascript, c#, html5, asp.net

Tengo una página en asp.net con tabs, que  habilita solo una sección a la vez pero cuando la página ejecuta un evento la página hace PostBack y no se conserva la ubicación, es decir, el tab activo. 
De esta forma si estoy en la sección del tab3 y doy clic sobre un botón la página se carga por defecto en el tab1.

Agrego el código:

```js
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('ul.tabs li a:first').addClass('activeTabs');
            $('.secciones article').hide();
            $('.secciones article:first').show();

            $('ul.tabs li a').click(function () {
                $('ul.tabs li a').removeClass('activeTabs');
                $(this).addClass('activeTabs');
                $('.secciones article').hide();

                var activeTab = $(this).attr('href');
                $(activeTab).show();
                return false;


            });
 });
</script>
```

```html
 <div class="wrap">
 <ul class="tabs">
  <li><a href="#tab1">Ejemplar</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab2">Ubicación</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab3">Investigadores</a></li>
 </ul>

        </div>
 <div class=secciones>
  <article class="Content_Ejemplar" id="tab1">
  </article>
  <article class="Content_Ubicación" id="tab2">
  </article>
  <article class="Content_Investigadores" id="tab3">
   <button class="button" runat="server" id="guardar1" onserverclick="GuardarD_Event">
           <i class="icon-floppy-disk"></i>
          </button>
  </article>
 </div>
```

¿Hay alguna manera de solucionar esto y decirle que conserve la posición?

Comment: Es difícil saber cual es el problema sin ver el código. Si los tabs forman parte de un control del servidor deberían mantener su estado a no ser que tú lo estés modificando en tu código.

Comment: Ya agregué el código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo resolví usando SessionStorage y un if, además, agregué un id para identificar a que `<a>`se debe asignar la clase activeTab.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            var Referencia = sessionStorage.getItem("href") 
            if ($.isEmptyObject(Referencia)) {
                $('ul.tabs li a:first').addClass('activeTabs');
                $('.secciones article:first').show();
            }
            else {
                var Id = "#" + sessionStorage.getItem("Id_a");
                $(Id).addClass('activeTabs');
                $(Referencia).show();
            }

            $('ul.tabs li a').click(function () {
                $('ul.tabs li a').removeClass('activeTabs');
                $(this).addClass('activeTabs');
                $('.secciones article').hide();

                var activeTab = $(this).attr('href');
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                sessionStorage.setItem("Id_a", id);
                sessionStorage.setItem("href", activeTab);
                $(activeTab).show();
                return false;
        });
```

```html
                <li><a id="1" href="#tab1">Clasificación</a></li>
                <li><a id="2" href="#tab2">Ejemplar</a></li>
                <li><a id="3" href="#tab3">Ubicación</a></li>
```

Dejo el código por si es útil para alguien.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que cuando haces postback la página se genera de nuevo en el servidor y se recarga por completo. En tu caso el tab activo no se mantiene en el estado de ningún control de servidor por lo que no se envía información al servidor sobre cual es el tab seleccionado y, por tanto, esta información no se puede utilizar al volver a cargar la página.

Lo que podrías hacer es crear un campo oculto con la propiedad `runat="server"` para que se envíe al servidor y se devuelva a cliente de forma automática. En este campo podrías almacenar el tab seleccionado cuando se hace click sobre uno de ellos.

Luego simplemente tendrías que cambiar tu código para que, en caso de que este campo tenga algún valor, se seleccione el tab indicado en lugar del primero (como se hace actualmente siempre):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var selectedTab = $('#selectedTab').val();
        var tabToSelect = selectedTab ? $('ul.tabs li a[href="' + selectedTab + '"]') : $('ul.tabs li a:first');
        tabToSelect.addClass('activeTabs');
        $('.secciones article').hide();
        $('.secciones article:first').show();

        $('ul.tabs li a').click(function () {
            $('ul.tabs li a').removeClass('activeTabs');
            $(this).addClass('activeTabs');
            $('.secciones article').hide();

            var activeTab = $(this).attr('href');
            $(activeTab).show();
            $('#selectedTab').val(activeTab);
            return false;


        });
    });
</script>

<div class="wrap">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#tab1">Ejemplar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Ubicación</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Investigadores</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
<div class=secciones>
    <article class="Content_Ejemplar" id="tab1">
    </article>
    <article class="Content_Ubicación" id="tab2">
    </article>
    <article class="Content_Investigadores" id="tab3">
        <button class="button" runat="server" id="guardar1" onserverclick="GuardarD_Event">
            <i class="icon-floppy-disk"></i>
        </button>
    </article>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="selectedTab" runat="server" />
```

Como puedes ver en el código en el campo `selectedTab` se almacena el tab seleccionado y se recupera de este campo al cargar de nuevo la página.

Comment: ya lo modifique pero no funciona sigue sucediendo lo mismo.

Comment: Asier una pregunta ya que la variable activeTab que se encuentra dentro del evento click contiene la referencia del tab actual como puedo conservar esta variable a pesar de que se recargue la página y que solo cambie si se entra de nuevo al evento?

Comment: El valor se conserva en el campo oculto `selectedTab`. WebForms mantiene en un campo oculto el estado de los controles de servidor (entre ellos cualquier campo marcado como `runat="server"`), de esta forma el estado de los controles es mandado ha servidor y utilizado para recargar la página manteniendo dicho estado. La información contenida en este campo oculto es lo que se denomina `ViewState`. Por eso al poner un valor en el campo `selectedTab` este valor está disponible en el servidor al hacer PostBack y se mantiene cuando se recarga la página.

Comment: Entiendo seguiré intentando, gracias